# Creating a directory alongside app.py

Tags: python

I am trying to create an instance of https://github.com/v/sniper

So far, I went to my sniper folder and executed:

```
 virtualenv venv
```

(was this right to account for step 1?)

then:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

(for step 2)

However, I got stuck on step 3. Create a db/ directory in the sniper folder (alongside app.py).

Maybe it was the part that says alongside app.py, but how would I go about this? Can I use makedir?

I am also new to python, so any helpful links that could help me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should run `cd sniper; mkdir db`...?   I'm assuming -- although it isn't clear from the docs -- that `sniper` should be the name of the top-level directory into which you've installed the code from this project.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I did all these commands after cd sniper. I Thanks